# Combine PCA with scale_size from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I have an expession matrix that I want to plot as a PCA. I would like to combine the points in the PCA with `scale_size`, where `scale_size` corresponds to the inverse p-value of the variable.

```
mydata

Gene         Pvalue       time1      time2        time3         time3
gene1        3.5           123123     123123       2535          21213
gene2        6.3           12312      7868         6732          6555
gene3        1.4           3423       435          1231          1323123
```

Is this possible in ggplot?